# SQL queries to Excel sheets - can't pass the first query

Tags: vb.net, excel

I am using below code to get data from multiple queries and pass the results to Excel sheets. The problem is it will keep populating the first sheet repeating infinitely the data from the first query:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim connetionString As String
        Dim connection As SqlConnection
        Dim command As SqlCommand
        Dim adapter As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        Dim i As Integer
        Dim sql1 As String
        Dim sql2 As String
        Dim File As String = "c:\temp\test.xlsx"

        connetionString = "Data Source=1.1.1.1;Database=PTR;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
        sql1 = "select * from xxxxx"
        sql2 = "select * from cccccc"
        'sql3 = "select * from zzzzz"
        'sql4 = "select * from xxxxx"
        'sql5 = "select * from ddddddd"
        connection = New SqlConnection(connetionString)

        Try
            connection.Open()

            command = New SqlCommand(sql1, connection)
            adapter.SelectCommand = command
            adapter.Fill(ds, "First Table")

            adapter.SelectCommand.CommandText = sql2
            adapter.Fill(ds, "Second Table")

            adapter.Dispose()
            command.Dispose()
            connection.Close()

            Dim oXL As Excel.Application = New Excel.Application
            Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook
            Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet
            Dim osheet1 As Excel.Worksheet
            Dim oRng As Excel.Range
            oXL.Visible = True
            Dim dc As DataColumn
            Dim dr As DataRow
            Dim colIndex As Integer = 0
            Dim rowIndex As Integer = 0
            oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add
            oSheet = CType(oWB.ActiveSheet, Excel.Worksheet)

            'retrieve first table data
            For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1

                For Each dc In ds.Tables(0).Columns
                    colIndex = colIndex + 1
                    oSheet.Cells(1, colIndex) = dc.ColumnName
                Next
                For Each dr In ds.Tables(0).Rows
                    rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
                    colIndex = 0
                    For Each dc In ds.Tables(0).Columns
                        colIndex = colIndex + 1
                        oSheet.Cells(rowIndex + 1, colIndex) = dr(dc.ColumnName)
                    Next
                Next
            Next

            osheet1 = oWB.Worksheets.Add(, oSheet, , )
            'retrieve second table data
            For i = 0 To ds.Tables(1).Rows.Count - 1
                For Each dc In ds.Tables(1).Columns
                    colIndex = colIndex + 1
                    osheet1.Cells(1, colIndex) = dc.ColumnName
                Next
                For Each dr In ds.Tables(1).Rows
                    rowIndex = rowIndex + 1
                    colIndex = 0
                    For Each dc In ds.Tables(1).Columns
                        colIndex = colIndex + 1
                        osheet1.Cells(rowIndex + 1, colIndex) = dr(dc.ColumnName)
                    Next
                Next
            Next

            oXL.Visible = True
            oXL.UserControl = True

            oWB.SaveAs(File)
            oRng = Nothing
            oXL.Quit()
            ExcelCleanUp(oXL, oWB, oSheet)
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
```

Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line:

```
For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1
```

runs for every line in the table

*inside* that, this line also runs for every row in the table:

```
For Each dr In ds.Tables(0).Rows
```

So if your table has 1,000 lines the innermost lines are going to run 1,000,000 times

Lose these lines (and their attached `next`)

```
For i = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count - 1

For i = 0 To ds.Tables(1).Rows.Count - 1
```

Comment: Damn! you were right! However, after first sheet is populated the second is created and document is closed (without adding the data)...